# I cannot connet to my kubernetes pod from webbrowser using clusterip

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a simple deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: load-balancer-example
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: load-balancer-example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: michalwolnicki/myapp:testlatests4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
```

michalwolnicki/myapp:testlatests4 image is my application that expose /test1 url unter 8080 port

next I have created a Nodeport:
kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=NodePort --name=example-service

when I login to pod and run this url:

## curl localhost:8080/test1

Successfully connected to: hello-world-c54bb6f45-npgxx# <-- this is the response from my application

Now I would like to open browser and reach this /test1 url outside of the cluster:

to do that I have to follow:

<port_from_Nodeport>/test1 or <32193>/test2

to get port:

PS C:\Windows\system32> k get svc example-service
NAME              TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
example-service   NodePort   10.105.206.191           8080:31113/TCP   26m

to get clusterIp:

PS C:\Windows\system32> k cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://127.0.0.1:36898

so my url that I have to use will look:

127.0.0.1:31113/test1

but when I paste it I cannot connect :/

on my parent house when I did this exercise it worked but when I moved to my apartment I cant do that :/

What Am I doing wrong ?

Im using minikube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found the solution why I cannot reach my url but I found a way how to bypass this problem.
I have downloaded a newest version of minikube (previous version I have deleted by minikube stop and removed .kube .minikube from c:/users/<my_user>)

and suddenly everything works fine now
and this time i spotted that the kube controlplane ip and core dns looks different: previously I had 127.0.0.1 and now 172.26.245.231

recently I have removed an entire minikube and problem happened again :/

Fortunately this time a found a page that describes problem in more details:

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7344

In my case below steps solved the problem:

```
    Enable Hyperv via Powershell --> "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All"
    Start --> minikube start --driver=hyperv
    Set --> minikube config set driver hyperv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expose your service in to 2 possible way, via [Port Forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod) or by using [Load Balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/#creating-a-service-for-an-application-running-in-five-pods)

Local Port Forwarding

```
kubectl port-forward svc/<service_name> <local_port>:<service_port> -n <namespace>

kubectl port-forward svc/example-service 8081:8080

curl localhost:8081/test1
```

Exposing using a Load Balancer

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=LoadBalancer --name=example-service -n <namespace>

## Run this command to get the LoadBalancer IP
kubectl get svc -A
```

Comment: unfortunately id doesnt work with load balancer as well :/ 
I can ping cluster ip 127.0.0.1 but I cannot reach my app :/

Comment: I should reach my url base on: 
<cluster-ip><port_exposed_by _loadbalancer>/test1 (/test1 is my application url that should work and Im able to cur it from pod)
I also exposed this outside using port 8080

Comment: You will not be able to reach the Cluster IP unless you login to one of the cluster node or your machine IP is under the same network .. if you're running this via minikube, you can do minikube ssh and do curl with the cluster IP ...

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to run using minikube. I would recommend expose the service as NodePort and use the minikube tunnel to access the service.

```
minikube service <service-name> --url
```

You can read more [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#example-of-nodeport)